# Salesforce upsert failing on an INVALID_FIELD error

Tags: .net, soap, salesforce, webservice-client

I'm using the standard Case object from Salesforce (we have some custom fields but that doesn't appear to be the problem). The Case has a linked subquery to its Comments, replicated in the SOAP API as CaseComments.

My test case (an NUnit test) for upserting records is to query() for one by case number, change something on the Case itself, and upsert that record again. I'm not even adding a new comment or anything. When the upsert call goes out, I get an INVALID_FIELD error stating that CaseComments doesn't exist on the Case table in the cloud. Of course it doesn't exist, and the API should know better. Or maybe I'm not telling it something. Help?

Relevant code:

```
[Test]
public void TestUpsertOfExistingRecord()
{
    var existingCase = sfRepository.GetCaseByNumber("00235452");

    var siteState = existingCase.Site_State__c;

    existingCase.Site_State__c = "Arkansas";

    //Tried the below line; the API didn't even recognize my Case as a valid object
    //existingCase.CaseComments = null;

    sfRepository.Save(existingCase);

    ...
}

//In the repository
public void Save<T>(T unboundInfo) where T : sObject
{
    service.Upsert(new sObject[]{unboundInfo});
}

//in a wrapper for the websevice
public void Upsert(sObject[] unboundInfo)
{
    //webService is the actual SOAP service client created by VS
    webService.upsert(unboundInfo.First().Id, unboundInfo);
}
```

UPDATE: As per some suggestions, instead of using the Case instance produced by the query, I am creating a new Case. That is failing with permission errors, and as the field I was trying to modify was a projection from another related object (the Account's address) it's understandable. I'll keep banging away at it; in the meantime, can anyone tell me why creating a new Case with the same information works, when cleaning out all related queries of a retrieved Case does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the upsert call should be the *name* of the ID field, not its value, so if you change your upsert method to be

```
//in a wrapper for the websevice
public void Upsert(sObject[] unboundInfo)
{
    //webService is the actual SOAP service client created by VS
    webService.upsert("Id", unboundInfo);
}
```

I think it should work. If your case number is an external ID (and marked as such in salesforce) you should be able to use that instead of "Id".

See [the salesforce.com upsert docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) for more info.

Comment: The other thing to remember is that update (and upsert which becomes an update) support partial updates, there's absolutely no reason to read the existing row first, you can construct a call that will update just the fields you need to update.

Comment: And finally you get the error because your read is reading in related data, and your subsequent write is sending that back, which isn't supported.

Comment: @superfell: Well actually, there is in the real application. Any window that will be updating these records is guaranteed to have retrieved one first, except when a brand new record is being created (which is a story I haven't gotten to yet). As far as your second message, sending back the object you retrieved is not supported. Great. Show me how it SHOULD happen in an answer and you get the uptick.

Comment: Case c = new Case(); c.id='xxxx'; c.Site_State__c = "Arkansas"; binding.update(new sobject[] {c});

Comment: :-P Gotcha. I got the test working; I can now update the Subject of my Case successfully, by creating a new Case, giving it the Id of the old one (Case Number would work too but I'm trying to keep it generic) and initializing the fields I want to change. It should translate to the actual use case. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

metadaddy's answer is correct, but I thought it might be useful to point out that the upsert method should really only be used if you need salesforce to determine whether to create the record(s) in question or just update them.  In this case you already know the ID of the record since you queried for it, so you might as well just do an update.

This way your operation will be slightly faster since you're saving salesforce from having to do a lookup to see if your record exists or not.  And you can be a good developer citizen by not wasting resources. :)

Comment: I'd tried a straight update as well before asking here; it doesn't require specifying the ID column, but it gave the same error.

Comment: It's important to make the distinction between metadata (what field you're upserting on) and data (the value of the id / external id field you're upserting with).  But it sounds like you're all set from the comments in metadaddy's answer.